# after_destroy callback claims object still exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, callback, rails-activerecord

I have an `after_destroy` callback that I'd expect to return `nil` but instead still has a value.

```
class WeighIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :check_in
  after_destroy :add_employee_weightloss

  def add_employee_weightloss
    p self.check_in.weigh_in.present? # returns true
  end
end
```

specs:

```
it "employee weightloss" do
  ci = CheckIn.create()
  wi = WeighIn.create(check_in_id: ci.id)

  wi.destroy
  expect(wi.reload).to eq(nil) # returns wi instead of nil
end
```

Comment: What does this return ? `record.destroyed?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `destroyed?` (or `exists?`, or `persisted?`) instead, cause `present?` just checks if the object is present, which is the correct behaviour after destruction (`destroy` itself returns deleted object).

```
def add_employee_weightloss
  p check_in.weigh_in.destroyed?
end
```

Also you should not use the following:

```
expect(wi.reload).to eq(nil)
```

cause if `wi` was destroyed you are going to get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception instead of `nil`. You can try the following:

```
it "employee weightloss" do
  wi = WeighIn.create(check_in: CheckIn.create)
  wi.destroy

  expect(wi.destroyed?).to eq(true)
end
```